# Need help to extract binary data from pickle

Tags: python

In MMO game user account statistics stored in .dat file. I know this is python pickle.
Im not professional in py (really i dont know this language) all then i can wrote

```
data = pickle.load(fp)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

And i get output like these

```
(8,
 {(2, 1): (1315840806,
'\x14\x00&#nNWH\x00\x00\x06\x90\xb3\x00\... lostsa bytes),
  (2, 17): (1327141794,
"\x14\x00\xa2\x93\x1aOS=\x00\x00\x06T\xaa\x00\x00\x8d\x06>\x00\x00\x00*\...
```

I wanna to extract information from this. Format should be like these

```
offs byte
  0  11
  1  00
  2  ac ;last batt time(4)
  3  8d ;last batt time(4)
  4  54 ;last batt time(4)
  5  4d ;last batt time(4)
  6  e8 ;battle lifetime(4)
  7  69 ;battle lifetime(4)
  8  00 ;battle lifetime(4)
  9  00 ;battle lifetime(4)
 10  04 ;maxfrags (1)
 11  db ;xp (4)
 12  95 ;xp (4)
 13  00 ;xp (4)
 14  00 ;xp (4)
 15  6f ;maxXP (2)
 16  06 ;maxXP (2)
```

and so on...

I has no idea how to get byte code in python, and what king of data is

```
(8,
 {(2, 1): (1315840806,
```

object? array? How to iterate over it. And how i can save data as binary string to analyse it? Code sample is appreciated, but some ways to move on should be useful to. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` denote lists, `()` denote tuples (immutable lists), and `{}` denote dictionaries (i.e. maps).

Consider:

```
(8,
 {(2, 1): (1315840806,
'\x14\x00&#nNWH\x00\x00\x06\x90\xb3\x00\... lostsa bytes),
```

At the top level, this is a tuple:

- The first element is the scalar `8`.
- The second element is a dictionary, of which we're only seeing part of the first entry:

  - The key of the entry is the tuple `(2, 1)`.
  - The value of that entry is also a tuple; it starts with `1315840806` followed by a string containing what looks like some binary data.

Hope you get the idea.